# Where is this building in Amsterdam with a façade looking like a bookshelf?

Tags: amsterdam, architecture, locate-this

A friend of mine was in Amsterdam this weekend, and he made an awesome photo of a building with a wall that looks like a book shelf:

[image]

Unfortunately he has no idea of the address and he doesn't have a picture of the building as a whole, nor its purpose. He wants to go back there again next week and take some more photos.

Can you give the address for this building?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, [tineye.com](https://tineye.com/search/e87385e0f3186fe317dca691647b54dc7a41339f) got a few hits, but nothing to solve the problem.

However, Google Image Search using your photo as the search parameter was more helpful.

One of the many hits was to a blog called `The Sticky Egg`, specifically [the post from November 13, 2011 called "Feeling Bookish"](http://stickyegg.com/2011/11/13/feeling-bookish/), which includes an address:

> De Batavier in Lootstraat [sic], Amsterdam.

[Then hunting around Google Street View, it seems to be 37 Lootsstraat.](http://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=52.363114,4.861622&sll=52.363112,4.861613&layer=c&cbp=11,221.43,,0,-38.01&cbll=52.363192,4.861547&gl=au&t=m&panoid=Qm0rXFtRoMu7Wc0SZuFecQ&z=17)

[image: 37 Lootsstraat]